# Issue with javax.sql.DataSource while unit testing with grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, junit

I've been using javax.sql.DataSource for processing sql queries in my services:

```
class SomeService {  
    javax.sql.DataSource datasource

    def someFoo(foo) {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM someDomain WHERE FOO = ${foo}"
        def result = sql.rows(query)
        return result
    }  
}
```

And I have created some unit tests for the services

```
class SomeServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    def service

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        service = new SomeService()
    }

    def testSomeFoo() {
        service.datasource = new javax.sql.DataSource
        def result = service.someFoo("foo")
        assertNotNull result
    }
}
```

I believe my services run good.
But, I get the following error from the test :

```
 Caused an ERROR
Must specify a non-null Connection
java.lang.NullPointerException: Must specify a non-null Connection
```

so, is that a problem with the testing framework or am I missing something here ?
I've also tried a similar situation with an executeQuery but that too throws a "MissingMethodException".

Can I create unit tests with these, because the same problem occurred with integration tests as well?

Is there any way that I could mock any of these or isolate the data parts, so as to just verify the methods?

Comment: I might be being stupid, but where and how is the `datasource` attribute of your service constructed?  I'm guessing you'll need to do this after `service = new SomeService()`

Comment: I guess I've missed that one, but even if I do add `javax.sql.DataSource datasource` to the test class and define the sql. The result happens to be the same.

Comment: you mean do `service.datasource = ...something...` in your test class after the `service = new SomeService()` line?  Not sure I understand when you say *"and define the sql"*

Comment: oops I think I tried it like `service.sql = new Sql(datasource)`, I thought I am doing it all wrong but then again I believe I couldn't just mock it like any other service or could I ?